# Difference between KPI and Scorecard?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reports, business-intelligence

What is the difference between KPI and Scorecard with respect to SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple answer for your question,

> A Key Performance Indicator (KPI) is a visual cue that communicates
>   the amount of progress made toward a goal.

[Learn more about KPIs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-publish-key-performance-indicators-kpis-HA010080027.aspx)

However,

> A scorecard is a type of report that displays a collection of key
>   performance indicators (KPIs) together with performance targets for
>   each KPI.

[Learn more about Scorecards](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/what-is-the-difference-between-a-dashboard-and-a-scorecard-HA101772797.aspx)

Comment: So basically we can say that a scorecard is a collection of KPIs?

Comment: indeed it is as stated by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

a scorecard is NOT a collection of KPIs as suggested here but rather threasholds defined regarding the KPIs.

If for example. I have a KPI of the number of products sold by a vendor over a month. A scorecard can be defined as 100 products sold and so if this KPI for the last month is 90 then the related scorecard will indicate a negaive alerts (e.g. red icon).